# How to access command line arguments with hyphens but without value in Go Lang

Tags: go, command-line

I want to access command line arguments with hyphens for example:

```
go run user.go -version
```

or

```
go run user.go --version
```

When I executing like this, I received the below error:

```
flag provided but not defined: -version
Usage of /tmp/go-build354377460/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/user:
  --version string
        prints current version and exits
exit status 2
```

Here is my code:

```
 package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var version string
    flag.StringVar(&version, "-version", "", "prints current version and exits")

    // Parse the flags
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Println(flag.Args())
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code where you define the flags.

Comment: What does the code look like? Do you use the standard flag library? Please provide the code of user.go stripped down to have a working repro

Comment: I have added my code in the question, please review. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a bool. Do not include the "-" in the flag definition.

```
func main() {
    var version bool
    flag.BoolVar(&version, "version", false, "prints current version and exits")
    flag.Parse()
    if version {
        fmt.Println("hello")
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(flag.Args())
}
```

Comment: Tried the code. But it is not working. I need to run with the hyphen
`go run user.go -version` like `--help`.

Comment: I added the complete main function to the answer. Give the exact command that you are running and the output you expect.

Comment: Yes it's working. I cannot get the arguments. My  `flag.Args()` is empty array.